# How to swap a group of column headings with their values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
a1  | a2  | a3  | a4 
--------------------- 
Bob | Cat | Dov | Edd 
Cat | Dov | Bob | Edd
Edd | Cat | Dov | Bob
```

and I want to convert it to

```
Bob | Cat | Dov | Edd
---------------------
a1  | a2  | a3  | a4
a3  | a1  | a2  | a4
a4  | a2  | a3  | a1
```

Note that the number of columns equals the number of unique values, and the number and order of rows are preserved

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) ***Required approach:***

A faster implementation would be to sort the values of the dataframe and align the columns accordingly based on it's obtained indices after [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

```
pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.argsort(df.values)], df.index, np.unique(df.values))
```

[image]

Applying `np.argsort` gives us the data we are looking for:

```
df.columns[np.argsort(df.values)]
Out[156]:
Index([['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'], ['a3', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4'],
       ['a4', 'a2', 'a3', 'a1']],
      dtype='object')
```

---

2) ***Slow generalized approach:***

More generalized approach while at the cost of some speed / efficiency would be to use `apply` after creating a `dict` mapping of the strings/values present in the dataframe with their corresponding column names.

Use a dataframe constructor later after converting the obtained series to their `list` representation.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda s: dict(zip(pd.Series(s), pd.Series(s).index)), 1).tolist())
```

---

3) ***Faster generalized approach:***

After obtaining a list of dictionaries from `df.to_dict` + `orient='records'`, we need to swap it's respective key and value pairs while iterating through them in a loop.

```
pd.DataFrame([{val:key for key, val in d.items()} for d in df.to_dict('r')])
```

---

*Sample test case:*

```
df = df.assign(a5=['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
```

Both these approaches produce:

[image]

---

***@piRSquared EDIT*** <sup>1</sup>

***generalized solution***

```
def nic(df):
    v = df.values
    n, m = v.shape
    u, inv = np.unique(v, return_inverse=1)
    i = df.index.values
    c = df.columns.values
    r = np.empty((n, len(u)), dtype=c.dtype)
    r[i.repeat(m), inv] = np.tile(c, n)
    return pd.DataFrame(r, i, u)
```

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I would like to thank user @[piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared) for coming up with a really fast and generalized numpy based alternative soln.</sub>

Comment: note that this only works under special circumstances where everything is neatly represented.  It's a great answer, I'm just pointing it out

Comment: Thanks. I guess OP had mentioned this to be the case at the bottom of their post. Otherwise, if not all the columns are equally represented, then I guess this would fail.

Comment: Appreciate very much for the edit. It'll take me some time to acclimate myself to all this high-end numpy procedures. I'll let your edit remain untouched till then :-)

Comment: I just edited your post because it was the best way to show you what I've done.  It's a great solution and I didn't want the credit.

Comment: Thank you for the one-liner solution :)

Comment: Added few more one-liners, if you're still interested.

Answer (score 5):

You can reshape it with stack and unstack with a swapping of the values and index:

```
df_swap = (df.stack()                     # reshape the data frame to long format
             .reset_index(level = 1)      # set the index(column headers) as a new column
             .set_index(0, append=True)   # set the values as index
             .unstack(level=1))           # reshape the data frame to wide format

df_swap.columns = df_swap.columns.get_level_values(1)   # drop level 0 in the column index
df_swap
```

[image]

Comment: I believe `to_frame` is not required, as `reset_index` returns a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response and for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

***`numpy` + `pandas`***

```
v = df.values
n, m = v.shape
i = df.index.values
c = df.columns.values

# create series with values that were column values
# create multi index with first level from existing index
# and second level from flattened existing values
# then unstack
pd.Series(
    np.tile(c, n),
    [i.repeat(m), v.ravel()]
).unstack()

  Bob Cat Dov Edd
0  a1  a2  a3  a4
1  a3  a1  a2  a4
2  a4  a2  a3  a1
```